# NaN Error report builder 3.0

Tags: reporting-services

New to SSRS. Using Report Builder 3.0. Trying to write a percentage expression.

This is the expression I have

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!lastfinancialyearflag.Value=1,0,Fields!Total_Delivered.Value)) /
Sum(IIf(Fields!lastfinancialyearflag.Value=1,0,Fields!Total_Orders.Value))
```

I have highlighted the cell then, and formatted it to percentage, and 2 decimal places.

However I keep getting some cells showing NaN. I have read this happens when the value is 0, but I have e.g 1/4 gives me `NaN` error.

Is there a way to rid the `NaN` error, or a better way of writing the percentage expression please?

Note:

Total Orders / Total Delivered columns are 1 and 0 values

lastfinancialyearflag column is 1 and 0 values, but only want to sum where value is 1.

Please help!

Comment: Can you get the sum in dataset?

Comment: using the sum above, but even when there are 8 orders, and 5 delivered, I am still getting 100.00%, but on other months, just shows NaN. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said "but only want to sum where value is 1." but your IIF expressions will return zero when lastfinancialyearflag is 1

try switch ing it round like this.

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!lastfinancialyearflag.Value=1, Fields!Total_Delivered.Value, 0)) /
Sum(IIf(Fields!lastfinancialyearflag.Value=1, Fields!Total_Orders.Value, 0))
```

Comment: Hi , this is bringing back the correct percentage answer I am looking for, but I am still having the NaN error - please help

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an extra check that the denominator (sum of total_orders.value) is not 0

```
=
Iif(
Sum(IIf(Fields!lastfinancialyearflag.Value=1,0,Fields!Total_Orders.Value))=0,
0,
Sum(IIf(Fields!lastfinancialyearflag.Value=1,0,Fields!Total_Delivered.Value))
)
/
Iif(
Sum(IIf(Fields!lastfinancialyearflag.Value=1,0,Fields!Total_Orders.Value))=0,
1,
Sum(IIf(Fields!lastfinancialyearflag.Value=1,0,Fields!Total_Orders.Value))
)
```

Comment: this has got rid of the NaN error, but the percentages are all coming back as 100 %. I have tried swapping the fields  Total_Orders / Total_Delivered  around, with no joy. example there was 8 orders with 5 delivered and this returns 100 % please help

Answer (score 0):

=
Iif(Sum(IIf(Fields!lastfinancialyearflag.Value=1, Fields!Total_Delivered.Value, 0))

=0
,0

,Sum(IIf(Fields!lastfinancialyearflag.Value=1, Fields!Total_Delivered.Value, 0)) /
Sum(IIf(Fields!lastfinancialyearflag.Value=1, Fields!Total_Orders.Value, 0)))

this worked, with a combo of using your guys answers.. thank you team A *